# How to select from an array column without getting malformed array errors

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I've spent a good hour or so googling and trying various combinations but without success.

I wish to select from a table where one of the columns is single dimensional array of varchar(255).

In normal SQL I use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email_domains @> '{"@google.com"}';
```

That works perfectly.
But now I want to do the same from code. So I have tried this:

```
domain = '@google.com'
sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email_domains @> '{%s}';"

cursor.execute( sql, [domain] )
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

and a whole load of various combinations of escaped ' and " but I cannot get it to work.

The error I get is this:

```
ERROR: malformed array literal: "{"
LINE 1: ... * FROM customers WHERE email_domains @> '{'@goo....
                                                         ^
DETAIL:  Unexpected end of input.
```

All help appreciated :)

Comment: Looks like the @g  in '@google' is being interrupted as an beginning of an array operator.  I don't have an environment at the moment to test but two options come to mind. 1) try escaping the @ in domain "domain='\@google'  2) Use the array constructor "WHERE email_domains @> ARRAY ['%s'];"

Comment: I tried changing the @google.com to anything.com without the @ just to see what error message I got. It was this
    ERROR:root:Failed to process Customer: syntax error at or near "anything"
LINE 1: ...FROM customers WHERE email_domains @> '{'anything.com'...

Comment: but escaping it gave this Failed to process Customer: syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: ...FROM customers WHERE email_domains @> '{'\@anything.co..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. At times I amaze myself with my stupidity...

The solution (for me) was to simply restructure my sql to this:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE %s  = ANY(email_domains);
```

Thanks to everyone who offered suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

psycopg2 converts lists to arrays for you.  I can't test this easily at the moment, but I believe this should work:

```
domain = ['@google.com']
# Let psycopg2 do the escaping for you, don't put quotes in there
sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email_domains @> %s;"

cursor.execute( sql, [domain] )
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work.. it gave this error malformed array literal: "@google.com" with the sql looking like this * FROM customers WHERE email_domains @> '@google.c...

Comment: Hmm, strange.  You did change domain to a list of (one) domains, right?

Comment: No, you are correct. I missed that! But.. the domain is a string '@google.com' so if i use that like this cursor.execute( sql, [domain]) I get this error: malformed array literal: "@google.com" if i use it like this cursor.execute( sql, [[domain]] ) I get this error: operator does not exist: character varying[] @> text[]

Comment: I have found a solution though and answered my own question accordingly.

Comment: @TheWelshDragon Yes in PostgreSQL `character varying` (`varchar`) and `text` are two different types. You need explicit type casting like `... WHERE email_domains @> %s::varchar[];`